# Dropdowning with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change name of people on a table list. I will change it by a dynamic dropdown on a table cell. On this code, I can not get names from the suggestion box to the searchbox. I pick up the name from dropdown but the name choosen doesn't appear on the search box,
Anyone who knows why?

```
<td title="Name of workers">

            <script>            
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getpersonallist.php",
                data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),

                success: function(data){
                    $("#dropdown-box").show();
                    $("#dropdown-box").html(data);
                    $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
                }
                });
            });
        });
```

//I know something is wrong on this JQ part below.

```
        function selectname(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);
        $("#dropdown-box").hide();
        }   
            </script>

<input  style="cursor: pointer; hover{background: yellow}" onclick="makeElementEditable(this)" 
onblur="updatePersonal(this,'<?php echo $rs['id'] ?>')" type="text" 
id="search-box"
value="<?php echo $rs['personal'] ?>"/>

<div id="dropdown-box"></div>

        </td>
```

More code (getpersonallist.php):

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {
$query ="SELECT * FROM personal WHERE personal like '%" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY personal LIMIT 0,6";
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
if(!empty($result)) {
?>
<ul id="selectname">
<?php
foreach($result as $name) {
?>
<li onClick="selectname('<?php echo $name["personal"]; ?>');"><?php echo $name["personal"]; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: post your server end code too.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you made any errors, but your function selectName() is never called, which could be a problem. I'm not sure where you want to call it either, but make sure it is called in an appropriate place.

Comment: Look at my last code. There is it called.  The problem is the dropdown doesn't work good when I use mysql database on my table. It only works for the first row then.